# hasMany and belongsTo and model in node js

Tags: node.js

I am defining one to many relationship in node.js but failed to make it work.

My model Table and Order is as follows:

```
    const Table =sequelize.define('Table', {
      num: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: true
      }
    });

    const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
      price: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL
      },
      date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: Date(),
        get() {
          return moment(this.getDataValue('date')).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        }
      },
      tableId : {
        type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references : { //  setting foreign key
          model : 'Table',
          key : 'tableId'
        }
      }
    });

    Table.hasMany(Order, {foreignKey: 'tableId'});
    Order.belongsTo(Table, {foreignKey: 'tableId'});
```

However, I cannot get order.table.num in my viewing EJS.

Is there anything I miss in the program? I am quite new to work with node.js. Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

BR,
Terry